How to use Hangfire with dependency injection in ASP.NET Core?
I would like to run a recurring job which has previously registered in the IoC in ASP.NET Core 8.
Something like this:

I register a class in the IoC
The framework takes care of all the dependencies that my class needs.
Then, I would like to use Hangfire to run a method from that registered class with all the dependencies resolved by the framework.

Basically I have this configuration for Hangfire.
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config
                       .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
                       .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                       .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
                       .UseInMemoryStorage());

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

After this I have the following MappingStoringGroup class registered in the IoC as follow:
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ITask, MappingTask>(nameof(MappingTask));
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ITask, StoringTask>(nameof(StoringTask));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, SqlRepository>();

    builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ITaskGroup>(nameof(MappingStoringGroup), (provider, key) =>
    {
        var taskGroup = new MappingStoringGroupBuilder()
                        .AddTask(provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITask>(nameof(MappingTask)))
                        .AddTask(provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITask>(nameof(StoringTask)))
                        .CreateTaskGroup();

        return taskGroup;
    });

What I am looking after would something like this:
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ITaskGroup>("job id", nameof(MappingStoringGroup), tg => tg.RunTasks(), Cron.Hourly);

app.Run();

There are two reasons why I have to register MappingStoringGroup like this in the IoC. First, all the task classes added to MappingStoringGroup have different dependencies in the constructor. Second, MappingStoringGroup.RunTasks() will be also called via controller, executing the tasks manually.
I tried to use Hangfire during the registration of MappingStoringGroup.
For instance:
builder.Services.AddKeyedScoped<ITaskGroup>(nameof(MappingStoringGroup), (provider, key) =>
    {
        var taskGroup = new MappingStoringGroupBuilder()
                        .AddTask(provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITask>(nameof(MappingTask)))
                        .AddTask(provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITask>(nameof(StoringTask)))
                        .CreateTaskGroup();
      
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("job id", () => taskGroup.RunTasks(), Cron.Hourly);

        return taskGroup;
    });

But it did not work. The Hangfire dashboard will show zero recurring jobs.

How about using JobActivator to implement IoC ?

Yes, I got to the same conclusion after reading this https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html and this https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/using-dependency-injection-with-hangfire-net-core-console-app/9499. I posted an example of the code as an answer, maybe it will help someone else

As commented in the thread, the solution is to create a custom activator:
    public class HangfireCustomActivator(IServiceScopeFactory container) : JobActivator
    {
        public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
        {
            using var scope = container.CreateScope();
            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITaskGroup>(type.Name);
        }
    }

And then use it in the Hangfire configuration.
    builder.Services.AddHangfire((provider, config) => config
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
        .UseInMemoryStorage()
        .UseActivator(new HangfireCustomActivator(provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>())));

    builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

This works.

We are using basically this approach:
Service Injection:
static void ConfigureHangfire(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services
        .AddHangfire(config =>
        {
            config
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseMemoryStorage()
                .UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
        })
        //.AddMetrics()
        //.AddMetricsEndpoints()
        .AddHangfireServer();
}

Application Configuration:
 app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions { DashboardTitle = "->APPLICATIONNAME<-" });

And off course you need implement jobs after application settings and you need manager for it:
Background Manager:
public static class BGManager
{
    public static void Enqueue<T>(object data) where T : IBackgroundJobs
    {
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue<T>(j => j.Execute(data));
    } 

    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
    public static void JobTest()
    {
       RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(nameof(JOBNAMEIMPLEMENTSPROCESSMETHODCLASS));
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<JOBNAMEIMPLEMENTSPROCESSMETHODCLASS>(nameof(JOBNAMEIMPLEMENTSPROCESSMETHODCLASS),
    job => job.Process(), "0 */1 * * *", new() { TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local });
    }

}

public interface IBGJobs
{
   void Execute(object data);
}

Then call it one time in program.cs:
    BGManager.JobTest();

Thats all you need goes for https://root:port/hangfire to access dashboard.
